# Refreshing partial view in ASP.NET MVC with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, highcharts

I´m currently creating a website with ASP.NET MVC5 and Highcharts:
http://highcharts.somee.com/Highcharts/CreateHighcharts

The selection and the charts are divided into partial views. My goal is to click on one button in the selection-View, passing over a variable to the controller, calling some functions and refreshing only the chart-partial-view.

```
<div id="divSelect" style="width: 100%;">
    @{Html.RenderPartial("_SelectPartial");}
</div>

<div id="divHighCharts" align="center"  style="width: 100%;">
    @{Html.RenderPartial("_CreateHighchartsPartial");}
</div>
```

_CreateHighchartsPartial:
(Is creating the charts)

```
@model  DotNet.Highcharts.Container
@(Model)
```

_SelectPartial:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Partial View chartPartial";
}
<link type="text/css" href="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3/css/ui-darkness/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link type="text/css" href="../../Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {


        $('#RefreshButton').click(function () {

           var IntervallHours = {
               ID: 94,
           }

           $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "/Highcharts/AjaxCall",
               data: IntervallHours,
               success: function (data) {

               }
           })
       });

        });
</script>


<div id="Auswahl" align="center">
    <br />
    <br />
    Startdatum: <input type="text" id="dateBegin" />
    Enddatum: <input type="text" id="dateEnd" />
    <button id="RefreshButton" class="button">Start</button>
    <br />
    <br />
    <button id="1hourButton" class="button">1 Stunde</button>
    <button id="24hoursButton" class="button">24 Stunden</button>
    <button id="1weekButton" class="button">1 Woche</button>
    <button id="1monthButton" class="button">1 Monat</button>
    <button id="3monthButton" class="button">3 Monate</button>
    <button id="allButton" class="button">Alle</button>
    <br />
    <br />
    <input class="sende01" type="button" value="1 Stunde">
    <input class="sende01" type="button" value="24 Stunden">
    <input class="sende01" type="button" value="1 Woche">
    <input class="sende01" type="button" value="1 Monat">
    <input class="sende01" type="button" value="3 Monate">
    <input class="sende01" type="button" value="Alle">
</div>
<hr />
```

controller(Highcharts):

```
public class HighchartsController : Controller
    {
        public int hourIntervallllllINT=6000;

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AjaxCall(UserModel model)
        {
            hourIntervallllllINT = model.ID;
            CreateHighcharts();
           return Json(new{success = true});
        }

...
...
...
        public ActionResult CreateHighcharts()
        {            
            GetDatabaseData(1, hourIntervallllllINT);
            createSeries(1, "tempValue");
            createSeries(1, "humidityValue");

Highcharts chart1 = new Highcharts("chart1")
...
...
...
 return View(new Container(new[] { chart1, chart2, chart3 }));
}
```

The new value for hourIntervallllllINT is passed correctly and the CreateHighcharts()-function is also working. My problem is, that the partial view is not reloading. I think there is something missing in the AJAX-function for success.

If you have a easier way to passing over javascript-variables to a controller, calling functions and refreshing a partial view, feel free to post.